# I have been trying setup a multi node kubernetes cluster for the Aerospike db as per the docs but getting error while installing operator using helm

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, aerospike

**After installing the helm and cert-manager required crds. As per the official docs:**

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert manager/releases/download/v1.12.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml
```

**when installing the cert-manager with helm install:**

```
helm install \
>   cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
>   --namespace cert-manager \
>   --create-namespace \
>   --version v1.12.0 \
>
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: 1 error occurred:
        * timed out waiting for the condition
```

Answer (score 3):

From the CRD link you mentioned above, it looks like there is a typo in the url (hyphen-missing).

It should be

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.12.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml
```

As CRDs are not installed in your case, cert-manager helm installation is timing out. Clean up the failed helm release using `helm delete cert-manager -n cert-manager` and retry your installation steps.

Or you can install both CRD and cert-manager in one go using command:

```
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.12.0 \
  --set installCRDs=true
```

Both these steps are mentioned in cert-manager official [doc](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/)

Comment: Thanks @Abhisek, but getting the same error. Idk why it's timed out. DO you have any ideas setting up a kubernetes cluster for aerospike enterprise db.

Comment: The issue you are facing is not related to Aerospike. Your cert-manager installation is failing which is a pre-requisite for Aerospike. Looks like an issue with your setup and above commands works on my Kubernetes cluster. Aerospike doesn't need any special Kubernetes cluster. Any self-managed or cloud-managed Kubernetes should work. Maybe looks at the logs of pods created in `cert-manager`  namespace to find out the issue.

Comment: If you are not tightly coupled with helm way of installation, you can try OLM based installation which is a recommended way of Aerospike Operator installation.

Comment: I am trying with that also in eks cluster but unable to install OLM which is the prerequisite for operator installation. any suggestion would be helfull :)